# C++ overhead no cabeçalho do método

Tags: c++, desempenho, método, directx

Eu estive analisando a performance de um renderizador DirectX através da ferramenta Performance Profiler do VS2015 e a mesma me apontou um overhead no cabeçalho de um método bastante requisitado do renderizador, conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os parâmetros estão sendo passados por referência, com exceção do PrimitiveType, que é um enum.

Existem outros métodos que também são muito requisitados, mas não apresentam nenhum overhead no seu cabeçalho.

O que pode estar causando isso?

Comment: Eu acho que ele está mostrando que há um consumo grande no método todo, depois mostrando as partes específicas onde gasta mais tempo dentro dele.

Comment: Eu pensei nisso, mas somando o consumo interno do método, a soma dá apenas 3%

Comment: Não seria a cópia? Me parece que type está sendo passado por valor.

Comment: Acho que não, porque o PrimitiveType é um enum. Tô achando que pode ser algum bug do Profiler. Talvés ele não esteja conseguindo identificar alguma linha, e esteja jogando a carga pro cabeçalho.

Comment: "Overhead no cabeçalho do método" é uma frase que não tem sentido no contexto da linguagem C++. Se houver overhead é na **execução** da função (ou método).

Comment: Mas se eu estiver recebendo um objeto relativamente grande por parâmetro, como valor e não como referência, vai haver um processamento pra gerar uma cópia deste objeto correto?

Comment: Mas aí seria na "chamada", e não no cabeçalho...você está usando "cabeçalho" onde deveria ser "chamada", p. ex: o título deveria ser "overhead na **chamada** do método.

Comment: Entendi @José X. Então realmente deve ser uma informação errônea do Profiler.

Comment: Na minha humilde opinião o overhead apontado seria pelo uso da interface IDirect3DTexture9 (o que não configura um overhead no cabeçalho e sim na utilização do parametro no método). Os métodos virtuais não podem ser otimizados como inline pelo compilador e também é necessário uma varredura na vtable para identificar qual método (base ou determinada classe filha) é adequada para cada uso.

Answer (score 0):

O parâmetro PrimitiveType pode estar causando esse overhead, pois é feita uma cópia de valores a cada chamada do método. Em C++ existe um "pulo do gato" para evitar o overhead que um tipo por valor possa causar quando passado como parâmetro à uma função/método. A função deve receber uma referência const daquele tipo ao invés disso, por exemplo:

```
//Overhead por conta da copia de valores.
int soma(int a, int b); 

//Passa a própria referência, e impede que elas sejam alteradas internamente na função.
int soma(const int& a, const int& b);
```

No seu caso PrimitiveType poderia ser passado da mesma forma:

```
Renderer::AddVertex(Vertex* vertex, const PrimitiveType& type, IDirect3DTexture* texture)
```

E não se preocupe, isso não muda nada na chamada do método.